# Syntax of emacs replace-regexp

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm trying to find every date and put quotes around it.  I thought this should be:

`M-x replace-regexp 201\d-\d\d-\d\d  <ret>   '\&'`

I also tried `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

it doesn't work.  But using `isearch-forward-regexp` I can type `[0-9][0-9]` and watch the targets highlight.  What am I doing wrong with the replace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emacs regexps don't have the common `\d` shorthand for `[0-9]`.

I just put the text 2011-04-01 into a new buffer, went back to the start of the buffer, and typed <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `201[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]` <kbd>RET</kbd> `'\&'` <kbd>RET</kbd>, and the date was surrounded by single quotes, as expected.

Answer (score 5):

`\d` is not supported in Emacs regular expression syntax (`C-h S regexp` has documentation on them).  You can use `[0-9]` as you did, or use the POSIX style `[[:digit:]]`.

However, what you did (with `[0-9]`) should have worked, and did in fact just work for me. If you're using a regular expression in a program you might also find `M-x regexp-builder` useful.

Comment: don't know what I did wrong, maybe I was subconsciously doing M-%, I caught myself doing that a few times today.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to escape the -s:

`M-x replace-regexp <RET> 201[0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9] <RET> '\&'`

Answer (score 0):

The regexps given are overly inclusive.  The following will also match invalid dates, like "2014-01-33", but not as many (assumes YYYY-MM-DD ordering):

"^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-2]-[0-3][0-9]"

or, to avoid dates like "2014-11-33" (but not like "2014-02-31" or "2014-00-00"), you could be slightly more restrictive:

"^20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-2]-\([0-2][0-9]\|30\|31\)"